# Scala XML validation by XSD and parsing

Tags: xml, scala, validation, xsd

I need to validate xml file by xsd, and parse xml if it possible. I have the next example:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream
import javax.xml.XMLConstants
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory

import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler

import scala.util.Try
import scala.xml.XML

object XMLTup extends App {
  val schema = {
    val factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI)
    val xsdStream = new FileInputStream("xsd.xsd")
    val schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(xsdStream))
    xsdStream.close()
    schema
  }

  val saxParser = {
    val f = SAXParserFactory.newInstance()
    f.setNamespaceAware(true)
    f.setSchema(schema)
    f.newSAXParser()
  }

  //DOESN'T WORK
  val xml1 = new FileInputStream("xml.xml")
  println {
    Try{XML.withSAXParser(saxParser).load(xml1)}
  }
  xml1.close()

  //WORKS
  val xml2 = new FileInputStream("xml.xml")
  val handler = new DefaultHandler() {
    override def error(ex: SAXParseException)  {
      println("Validation Error!")
    }
  }
  saxParser.parse(xml2, handler)
  xml2.close()
}
```

When I use scala XML (DOESN'T WORK), I got Success and haven't validation error, but the next code (WORKS) I got "Validation Error" message. Why is it happend? How can I validate XML by XSD with scala XML class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly, it was found that scala XML use NoBindingFactoryAdapter which inherited FactoryAdapter witch inherited DefaultHandler. DefaultHandler have the next method:

```
public void error (SAXParseException e)
    throws SAXException
{
    // no op
}
```

You need override this method for handle error message of xml validation. One way to do it is create own object of scala trait XMLLoader and override adapter and parser if necessary:

```
 //NOW, IT WORKS
  val xml1 = new FileInputStream("xml.xml")
  println {
    Try{
      val loader = new XMLLoader[Elem] {
        override def adapter: FactoryAdapter = new NoBindingFactoryAdapter() {
          override def error(e: SAXParseException) = {
            throw e
          }
        }

        override def parser: SAXParser = saxParser
      }
      loader.load(xml1)
    }
  }
  xml1.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

I use scalaxb with sbt (my xsd files are located in subproject `genscalaxb`).

Add to project/plugin.sbt:

```scala
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("public")

addSbtPlugin("org.scalaxb" % "sbt-scalaxb" % "1.2.1")
```

Add to your build.sbt (map is optional - for custom packages):

```scala
lazy val `genscalaxb` = Project("genscalaxb", file("genscalaxb")).settings(scalaxbSettings: _*).settings(
  packageNames in scalaxb in Compile := Map(new URI("https://github.com/ajozwik/mvn2sbt") -> "pl.jozwik.gen",
    new URI("http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0") -> "org.maven"),
  sourceGenerators in Compile <+= scalaxb in Compile
)
```

Put your xsd files to: `genscalaxb/src/main/xsd`

I use in in function, [see in github](https://github.com/ajozwik/mvn2sbt/blob/master/converter/src/main/scala/pl/jozwik/mvn2sbt/DirProjectExtractor.scala#L58):

```
 private def handlePomFile(pomXml: File, parent: Option[MavenDependency]) = {
    val xmlFromFile = Try(xml.XML.loadFile(pomXml)) match {
      case Success(pom) => pom
      case Failure(th) =>
        logger.error(s"${pomXml.getAbsolutePath} failed to be parse")
        throw th
    }
    val pomModel = scalaxb.fromXML[org.maven.Model](xmlFromFile)
    createProjectMap(pomXml.getParentFile, pomModel, parent)
  }
```

The xsd file is [maven-4.0.0.xsd](http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd)

Xml files - are poms.